# Best approach for simple link within UITextView

Tags: iphone, linker, hyperlink, uitextview

I am creating a dictionary lookup application.  The user selects a word from a UITableView and the app displays the definition.  In some cases the word will be similar to another word, so I want to display "See Also:" followed by a list of similar words that when touched, bring up another definition.

In searching here on links within UITextViews, most of the answers involve linking out to the web, which is not really what I need. I simply want to get control when the user touches a word so that I can change the view.

Is UIWebView the only way to do this, or did I miss something obvious in the SDK?  Also, I'd prefer to stay within the native SDK and not go the three20 route.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use another `UITableView` to make this work. Your list of similar words will probably be in `NSArray` format already, so it would be pretty easy to set up another `UITableView` instead of a `UITextView` to display the list, and given that you already have this code working for the main `UITableView`, you already know how to make them clickable!

Comment: Excellent!  The obvious always seems to escape me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A UIWebView will be the only thing that suits here I'm afraid.  Data detectors are the only way to link inside of a UITextView, and they will only respond to the appropriate data types (Phone number, web page, address)...

Links can be done the normal way:

```
<a href='http://someotherword'>someotherword</a>
```

Setup the webviewdelegate to snag any link requests (and prevent them from being opened in the browser) so that you can open them in your own handler:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
  if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) return YES; // Allow direct loading

  NSString *myWord = [[request URL] host];
  // do something with myWord... say open another word
  return NO; // Don't let the browser actually perform this navigation
}
```